# NodeJS and React - LAN connection not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, lan

### Description

I have a Node server and React App running on my notebook Ubuntu 18.04.
**Notebook ip is 10.0.0.101**

I tried to connect my desktop to this server on the same network
**Desktop ip is 10.0.0.100**

Node is running on **PORT=3333**
React is running on **PORT=3000**

I can ping my notebook from my desktop but when I try to connect to node using Insomnia or to http://10.0.0.101:3000 from my desktop I cannot reach.

### Errors

When try to connect to backend with Insomnia
Error: Couldn't connect to server

When try to connect to app on 10.0.0.101:3000
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

### What I've done

1. I already changed the node listen and specified the port and the ip but it didn't work.
2. I tried to use my phone as router and connect from my phone to react on my notebook and also didn't work.
3. I've tried so many things since I can't remember them all.

I'm also creating a react-native app and when I try to connect to my mobile using Expo, it just works using tunnel, but cannot get data from the backend.

Please save me.
Thanks

Comment: `...but it didn't work.` Can you please be more precise and share the errors messages that you get ?

Comment: When try to connect to backend with Insomnia
Error: Couldn't connect to server

When try to connect to app on 10.0.0.101:3000
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making many failed attempts, I realized that the problem was in my notebook.
I checked my firewall and it was disabled and still cannot get acess to my notebook on LAN. But finally I discovered what have to be done

### Solution

You have to open the specific port for TCP traffic

Ubuntu:

```
sudo ufw allow <PORT-NUMBER>/tcp
```

or for Red Hat Enterprise

```
firewall-cmd --add-port <PORT-NUMER>/tcp
```

Reference: [Examples of how to open firewall ports](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/STXKQY_5.0.4/com.ibm.spectrum.scale.v5r04.doc/bl1adv_firewallportopenexamples.htm)